# PSExec shutdown list of servers

Tags: windows-server-2012, scripting

I have a system I inherited that used a simple psexec script and a list of servers to automatically shut down the servers in the list should a temperature threshold be reached or the UPS only has a few minutes of battery remaining. This was executed by AVTech Device Manager. It is no longer working (and likely has not since I have been here). If I execute the script manually from an administrative command prompt (Windows Server 2012 r2) I get this error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The script in question looks like this

```
c:\avtech\psexec @c:\avtech\scripts\serverlist.txt c:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 0 >"c:\avtech\log\shutdownlog.txt 2>&1
```

and the serverlist.txt file is currently a file with just one entry

```
server.domain.local
```

If I substitute the actual server name for the serverlist.txt file it works fine

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\AVTECH\psexec \\server.domain.local c:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 0 >c:\shutdownLog.txt 2>&1
```

So it all works just fine if I **don't** have psexec grab from that list of servers. And, yes, the path to the list of servers is correct.

No doubt there is a simple and obvious error here somewhere but my experience with this kind of thing is pretty weak, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of fiddling around with psexec for this, why not just call [shutdown.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) directly with the `/m` switch?

```
shutdown.exe -m \\server.domain.local -s -f -t 0
```

You can even keep your list of servers in the same file by using a for command. See the [for documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) if you want to use a non-default (space and tab) delimiter:

```
for /f %%SERVER in (c:\avtech\scripts\serverlist.txt) do (
    shutdown.exe -m %%SERVER -s -f -t 0
)
```

Comment: if there is a way to pass a list of servers to shutdown that is fine. I just am not sure how to do that.

Comment: [You can use a batch for loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend [PsShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx)? You seem more inclined for PsTools but I don't think PsExec is the proper tool.

For shutdown -m, you could iterate over it with a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) I suppose?

Comment: I would imagine that since this is by the same folks that my issue will persist as the list of computers is called in exactly the same way. I also have a couple of other things that use PSExec similarly and I would like to just get this working without introducing another, nonstandard, command.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use it like this:

```
psexec.exe \\LAB-PC1 -u LAB-Pc01\admin -p S3cret! -i -d cmd /c shutdown /r /f /t 1
```

Command line break down:

(psexec part)

- -i Interactive session
- -d don't wait for process to terminate

(cmd part)

- cmd windows shell on remote host
- /c  Run command and then terminate from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)
- shutdown windows shutdown command
- /r restart   (/h if you want to shutdown)
- /f Force shutdown, don't wait for processes
- /t 1  timeout of 1 second

You can replace my \LAB-PC1 with your @server-list.txt and apply it to a list of hosts

**EDIT**

```
C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\push_software_installer>SO-psexec-server-list.cmd
C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\push_software_installer>\\lab.local\central-store\Software\psTools\psexec
@server-list.txt -u LABDOMAIN\administrador -p S3cret!! -i -d cmd /c w32tm /monitor > output.txt

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Starting cmd on LAB-PC1...e on LAB-PC1...
cmd started on LAB-PC1 with process ID 30820.     <====
Couldn't access LAB-PC2-disabled:
O identificador Ú invßlido.
Couldn't access LAB-PC3-disabled:
O identificador Ú invßlido.
Couldn't access LAB-PC4-disabled:
O identificador Ú invßlido.
Couldn't access LAB-PC5-disabled:
O identificador Ú invßlido.
Connecting to LAB-PC5-disabled...
C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\push_software_installer>`
```

My server-list.txt

```
LAB-PC1
LAB-PC2-disabled
LAB-PC3-disabled
LAB-PC4-disabled
LAB-PC5-disabled
```

Note: my lab pc language is in PT-PT

It works on my end :)

Hope it helps

Comment: yes if I specify ONE computer in the command line, like you show, it works a treat. The problem comes when you use "@" to specify a list of computers to command is when it falls down.

Comment: Please see my edit. I added a working example from my lab network with the @server-list.txt file working

Comment: I don't know what "PT-PT" is. I can't run psexec in interactive mode as I am not executing it manually, except for testing purposes. It is being run by the avtech service (logged on as a domain admin) and if I run the command modified to make it similar to yours (c:\avtech\psexec @c:\avtech\scripts\serverlist.txt -d cmd c:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 0 >"c:\avtech\log\ShutdownLog.txt 2>&1) I get the same error.

Comment: OK, Let me try to run this from a non interactive service. I'll try to reproduce the problem. PT-PT is the language of the operating systems (because of the error messages) - no big deal.